# Can I add 'x-amz-server-side​-encryption': 'AES256' to files uploaded to the Content module?

Tags: quickblox

in regards to the Javascript SDK for quickblox, when calling the QB.content.createAndUpload() method, how can I add form data for 'x-amz-server-side​-encryption': 'AES256'?  I need our file uploads to S3 to be encrypted at rest.  for 'POST' actions, form data is sent, for 'PUT' request headers should be sent.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html